# Why is a field with a JAXB object not recognized as persistent state by OpenJPA?

Tags: java, openjpa

I want to persist the XML of a JAXB object in a CLOB column in the table of the owning entity. OpenJPA ships with support for such constructs using its [XMLValueHandler](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.0/apidocs/index.html).

I followed [this tutorial](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/info/zseries/ae/tejb_jpaColMap.html) from IBM.

My sample code is:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class EntityContainingXml {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    @Strategy("org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.XMLValueHandler")
    @Column(name = "xml")
    @Lob
    private SomeJaxbType xmlStuff;
    //...
}
```

However the field `xmlStuff` is not recognized as persistent state by the OpenJPA enhancer. It does not make a change if `SomeJaxbType` is contained in the persistence unit.

What do I need to do so that the OpenJPA enhancer recognizes the field `xmlStuff` as persistent state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a classpath issue due to maven dependencies. I can't say what exactly caused this issue. The original classpath contained some combination of the org.apache.openjpa artifacts openjpa-persistence-jdbc, openjpa-persistence, openjpa and openjpa-all. That was causing the `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataFactory` to be used during build time enhancement. But the parser `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.AnnotationPersistenceMetaDataParser.AnnotationPersistenceMetaDataParser` created by this factory is not able to recognize `@Strategy`.

Now only openjpa-persistence-jdbc is currently used as a compile time dependency. And the build time enhancement has a dependency on the artifact openjpa.

I debugged through the maven build to find that out. In my case it was not possible to use the configuration property `openjpa.MetaDataFactory` to set the appropriate meta data factory, because it caused a class cast exception. I then started to throw out OpenJPA. During that I build and ran the application once more and it suddenly worked.